# Alert does not appear upon click of the second page?

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with jQuery alert using jQuery. On the first page on page load, when I click the link the jQuery alert works.

But, when I click on the second page and click the link, jQuery alert does not appear even when I go back to the first page.

This is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(".textad_paginator").click(function(){


            var page =  jQuery(this).attr("id");

            var str = new String(page);
            var page = str.charAt( str.length-1 );

            var pages = jQuery("#txtad_pages").val();
            var txtadcount = jQuery("#txtadcount").val();
            var supplier_id = jQuery("#supplier_id").val();

            jQuery.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: publicdomainobj+"archives/directory_archive.obj.php",  
                    data: "supplier_id="+supplier_id+"&page="+page+"&type_list=textads",  


                    success: function(getdata){  



                            jQuery("#textad_archive_container").html('');
                            jQuery("#textad_archive_container").html(getdata);

                                jQuery("#more_textads").show(); 
                                jQuery(".textad_paginator").css("font-weight","normal");    
                                jQuery(".textad_paginator").css("color","#666666");                             
                                jQuery("#textad"+page).css("font-weight","bold");
                                jQuery("#textad"+page).css("color","#017F9A");


                            if(page<pages){
                                jQuery(".textad_count_indicator").html(page*10);

                            }else{
                                jQuery(".textad_count_indicator").html(txtadcount);             

                            }


                    } 
            });

            return false;
        });

        jQuery(".textads").click(function(){
            alert(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
        });
```

Did I break some jQuery rules or scripting?

Please see the links for your reference, http://beta.bridalbook.ph/wedding-suppliers/tenstringedlyre PACKAGES section.

Comment: Works for me, Hope this is not a backlink post :P

Answer (score 0):

Try to change click like this:

```
jQuery(".textads").live('click', function(){
        alert(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

made some work-around:

I modify the code like:

```
 jQuery(".textad_paginator").on('click', function(){


        var page =  jQuery(this).attr("id");

        var str = new String(page);
        var page = str.charAt( str.length-1 );

        var pages = jQuery("#txtad_pages").val();
        var txtadcount = jQuery("#txtadcount").val();
        var supplier_id = jQuery("#supplier_id").val();

        jQuery("#textad_archive_container").load("<?=$config['publicdomain']?>/data_textads.php?supplier_id="+supplier_id+"&page="+page+"&type_list=textads");


        if(page<pages){
            jQuery(".textad_count_indicator").html(page*10);

        }else{
            jQuery(".textad_count_indicator").html(txtadcount);             

        }

        jQuery("#more_textads").show(); 
        jQuery(".textad_paginator").css("font-weight","normal");    
        jQuery(".textad_paginator").css("color","#666666");                             
        jQuery("#textad"+page).css("font-weight","bold");
        jQuery("#textad"+page).css("color","#017F9A");

        return false;
    });
```

and data_textads.php with jQuery code :

```
jQuery(".textads").on('click', function(){
      alert(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
});
```

and it works! thanks you guys.